ConnectApiException:The credential couldn't be saved because it's associated with an external credential with the folowing authentication protocol:Jwt
I was able successfully create externalCredential and namedCredential using connectApi's createExternalCredential and createNamedCredential methods. However while I am trying to update just any of the parameters of an existing externalCredential using connectApi's patchCredential or updateCredential methods, It's throwing the following error.
"ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: The credential couldn't be saved because it's associated with an external credential with the following authentication protocol: Jwt"
Below is the externalCredential JSON that was created using createExternalCredential method:
{
    "authenticationProtocol" : "Jwt",
    "developerName" : "EXT_CRED_TEST_V1",
    "masterLabel" : "EXT CRED TEST V1",
    "parameters" : 
    [
        {
            "parameterName" : "SigningCertificate",
            "parameterType" : "SigningCertificate",
            "parameterValue" : "TestParameter"
        }, 
        {
            "parameterDescription" : "Key Id",
            "parameterName" : "kid",
            "parameterType" : "JwtHeaderClaim",
            "parameterValue" : "TestParameter"
        }, 
        {
            "parameterDescription" : "Issuer",
            "parameterName" : "iss",
            "parameterType" : "JwtBodyClaim",
            "parameterValue" : "https://someurl.com"
        }, 
        {
            "parameterDescription" : "Subject",
            "parameterName" : "sub",
            "parameterType" : "JwtBodyClaim",
            "parameterValue" : "TestParamValue"
        },
        {
            "parameterDescription" : "Audience",
            "parameterName" : "aud",
            "parameterType" : "JwtBodyClaim",
            "parameterValue" : "TestParameterValue"
            }
    ],
    "principals" : 
    [ 
        {
            "principalName" : "Authentication",
            "principalType" : "NamedPrincipal",
            "sequenceNumber" : 1
        } 
    ]
}

Below is the credentialInput JSON that i am using to update the externalCredential:
{
    "authenticationProtocol" : "Jwt",               
    "externalCredential" : "EXT_CRED_TEST_V1",              
    "principalName" : "Authentication",             
    "principalType" : "NamedPrincipal",
    "credentials": {
        "username": {
            "value": "you@example.com",
            "encrypted": false
        },
        "password": {
            "value": "test1234",
            "encrypted": true
        }
    }
}

There is NO enough documentation regarding updating the external credentials. I don't see anything about this error. Can someone help me to get rid off this error and a working code to update the external credential.
